# Loader.js MissingModule at runtime after upgrading ember-auto-import to v2

Tags: ember.js

My app is on v3.28 of Ember. After upgrading ember-auto-import from 1.12.0 to 2.6.0 (and adding webpack 5), I'm getting a missingModule error from loader.js for dependencies of my app's addons. I'm sure the issue is probably something that needs to be reconfiged in ember-cli-build, but i can't figure it out. Can somebody help point me in the right direction?

**Instance of this error:**
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `lodash.merge` imported from `ember-rollbar-client/services/rollbar`

ember-rollbar-client: 0.9.0
-> lodash.merge: 4.6.1

**Package versions:**
ember-cli: 3.28.6
node: 14.17.0
os: darwin arm64
ember-auto-import: 2.6.0
webpack: 5.75.0

Comment: is lodash.merge in ember-rollbar-client's dependencies? (also, can you try ember-auto-import 2.6.1?)

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli, yes lodash.merge is a dependency of ember-rollbar-client and not a dependency of the host app. I was trying to use the -> arrow to indicate that, sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I'll try 2.6.1 and report back

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I tried ember-auto-import 2.6.1 and I'm still getting the same result unfortunately. Addons (e.g., ember-rollbar-client) using  ember-auto-import v1.x should still be compatible w/ host apps on e-a-i v2, right?
Any other info I can provide to help out here?

Comment: correct, however I'd use overrides / resolutions to force the same ember-auto-import across all dependencies, as you get a smidge of a perf boost to your build.

do you happen to have an open source reproduction? I'd be happy to debug this

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I just realized there's also a console error that looks like this:
`Refused to execute script from 'http://staging.icispatients.localhost/assets/chunk.vendors-node_modules_c3_c3_js-node_modules_lodash_merge_index_js-node_modules_moment-range_di-ba372f.00091a801ef42d78b63b.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` But that chunk doesn't appear in the /assets/ dir in Sources (i'll try to add a screenshot to illustrate).

Comment: I don't think these chunks were being created before (on e-a-i v1.x). Is the answer maybe that the chunk-generation should be disabled? or that the chunk file is getting injected into `index.html`, but the file is somehow failing to generate in /assets/ or is ending up in the wrong dir?

happy to provide an open source reproduction if you could point me to an example of what that might look like. sorry i'm a little unfamiliar w/ this process.

Comment: I'm not sure how to disable chunk generation, but you don't want to do this, because chunks make for a better experience for your users. No need to apologize! To make an open source reproduction, you `ember new my-app`, and then push to a repo on github, and make changes to that my-app until it exhibits the behavior you're experiencing on your non open source app.
if you check dist/assets tho, you should see the chunks there. my hunch is that something with your dev server isn't proxying all requests to your local machine?